# Why is there such a long delay between receiving the invoke and the actual execution of the method?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

On this logs you can see there are like  18 seconds between the call received and the execution.

```
org1peer0_1  | 2022-03-09 17:31:01.797 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.odins.com-GuardianSC1-86eed1b224916b39f365986d78daa728b34b4302900b7823223838e2bd9579a1] func2 -> INFO ac9ca1 17:31:01:796 INFO    org.hyperledger.fabric.contract.ContractRouter processRequest                    Got invoke routing request       
org1peer0_1  | 2022-03-09 17:31:18.986 UTC [peer.chaincode.dev-peer0.org1.odins.com-GuardianSC1-86eed1b224916b39f365986d78daa728b34b4302900b7823223838e2bd9579a1] func2 -> INFO ac9ca2 17:31:01:797 INFO    org.hyperledger.fabric.contract.ContractRouter processRequest       Got the invoke request for:METHOD [reallybigstring]
```

I'm using one orderer and one org with one peer. Everything on docker version: hyperledger/fabric-peer:2.0

On the chaincode I'm using:

```
    compileOnly 'org.hyperledger.fabric-chaincode-java:fabric-chaincode-shim:2.2.+'
    implementation 'com.owlike:genson:1.5'
    testImplementation 'org.hyperledger.fabric-chaincode-java:fabric-chaincode-shim:2.2.+'
```

And, finally, as parameter of the method I'm passing a string with about 20.700 characters. In addition to this, I can say that with a smaller string the time is reduced.

Comment: If I understand correctly you are saying that string size is "20,700" characters, in that case this delay is expected. see the following analysis, you can see that as the asset size increases latency (delay) increases and throughput decreases. https://hyperledger.github.io/caliper-benchmarks/fabric/performance/2.1.0/nodeContract/nodeSDK/evaluate/get-asset/#benchmark-results

Comment: It is a submit transaction, not a evaluate. Yet you think my performance is the expected one. The average latency on 32K bytes in couchDB table is less than 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not invoke function's execution time.

It is processing time that processes your string argument.

Between both logs, It only 'stub.getStringArgs().size()'

```
private Response processRequest(final ChaincodeStub stub) {
    logger.info(() -> "Got invoke routing request");
    try {
        if (stub.getStringArgs().size() > 0) {
            logger.info(() -> "Got the invoke request for:" + stub.getFunction() + " " + stub.getParameters());
            final InvocationRequest request = ExecutionFactory.getInstance().createRequest(stub);
            final TxFunction txFn = getRouting(request);
            logger.info(() -> "Got routing:" + txFn.getRouting());
            return executor.executeRequest(txFn, request, stub);
        } else {
            return ResponseUtils.newSuccessResponse();
        }
    } catch (final Throwable throwable) {
        return ResponseUtils.newErrorResponse(throwable);
    }
}
```